# Persist in file tree structure and node references

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have a recursive Tree data structure where each node can have zero or more children like in the snippet.

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

There is a root node and all other nodes are its children (or children of its children...) This is a big collection (millions of items) so I prefer not to load in memory.
I was thinking a way to save/persist this to a file.
For each item I want to save the value (string) and the position in the file of each child.

`|value of node1|number of children|child1 location (int), child2, ...,childN|`

`|value of node2|number of childs|child locations of node 2|`

Not sure if I explained well but I want the pointers/references of Children to be the actual locations in the file.
My problem is pre-calculating the positions where every node item will start. I suppose this will be some recursive method that saves for each Node its value, number of children and locations of each child.
The problem is that for every node the value has variable length and number of items is not fixed.

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public void Test()
    {
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("my file.dat"));

        //node 1 has 2 childs

        //node 1
        binaryWriter.Write("node1 value");
        binaryWriter.Write(2); //2 children
        binaryWriter.Write(10); // location of child 1
        binaryWriter.Write(20); // location of child 2

        //child 1
        binaryWriter.BaseStream.Position = 10;
        binaryWriter.Write("child1 value");
        binaryWriter.Write(5); //5 children
        // write locations of childen of child 1

        //child2
        binaryWriter.BaseStream.Position = 20;
        binaryWriter.Write("child2 value");
        binaryWriter.Write(3); //3 children
        // write locations of childen of child 2

        //...
        //continue for every 

    }
}
```

The usage of the file will be like

1. go to root position 0
2. read the value and any child location i.e. 456 and 789
3. got to position 456 and read ...
4. go to 789 ....

Comment: Millions of items in memory is not necessarily a problem. How do you plan to create the file without having all of the items in memory? What you're proposing is possible, but it may not be worth the effort. If you're certain you want to do this, you can recursively pre-compute the locations by computing the size of each node. Or your recursive writer can return the position where the next data will be written and you can update the already-stored parent with that data.

Comment: Creating the file will be done by loading in memory on my tool that I'm trying to create, but only once. After that I'll deploy in the cloud the main app + the (read only) file next to it.  The plan is that main app will never load the whole file, (just jumping in different location to retrieve the data). I imagine the writer will be similar to malloc (allocate for writing to next available position).

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't been tested, but something like this should work:

```
public long WriteNode(BinaryWriter writer, TreeNode node) 
{
    // record the position where we will write this node
    long initialPosition = writer.BaseStream.Position;
    
    // write node content
    writer.Write(node.Value);
    
    // write number of children
    writer.Write(node.Children.Count);
    
    // write child position vector initialized with zeros 
    long vectorPosition = writer.BaseStream.Position;
    for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; ++i) 
    {
        writer.Write(0L);
    }

    // write children, updating position vector as we go
    for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; ++i)
    {
        // write the child and get the position where it was written
        var childNode = node.Children[i];
        long childPosition = WriteNode(writer, childNode);
        
        // compute the file position where we need to store the child's position
        long childVectorPosition = vectorPosition + (i * sizeof(long));
        
        // write the child's file position into the vector while retaining the current file position
        long currentPosition = writer.BaseStream.Position;
        writer.BaseStream.Seek(childVectorPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
        writer.Write(childPosition);
        writer.BaseStream.Seek(currentPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    }

    // return file position where this node was written
    return initialPosition;
}
```

You recursively write nodes, initializing the child positions as zero, and backtracking where necessary to update the child positions with the actual value.

Comment: Thanks . I'll try it